# Escaping verbatim string literals

Tags: c#, string, escaping, verbatim-string

I have the following string which won't compile:

```
String formLookupPull = @"SELECT value1, '"+tableName+"', '"+columnName+"' FROM lkpLookups WHERE ""table"" = '" + tableName + "' and ""field"" = '" + columnName + "';";
```

The offending sections are :

```
""table"" =
```

and

```
""field"" =
```

The compiler is getting all mixed up on the escape sequence.  Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: thanks for the speedy replies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that not all the strings you are concatenating are *verbatim* string literals, only the first portion of the concatenation is.

In other words,

```
@"SELECT value1, '"
```

is the only *verbatim* literal in the entire statement to build the final string.

You would need to add @ in front of the rest of your strings to make them all verbatim.

Which would make it look like:

```
String formLookupPull = @"SELECT value1, '"+tableName+ @"', '"+columnName+ @"' FROM lkpLookups WHERE ""table"" = '" + tableName + @"' and ""field"" = '" + columnName + @"';";
```

Answer (score 17):

To address your title question...

To escape the quote in a verbatim string literal, use the quote-escape-sequence `""` (that's two quote characters)

```
string a = @"He said ""Hi!""..."; // He said "Hi!"...
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) for more details on escaping, etc.

Note that in your posted code, the only verbatim string is the very first one (with the `@` before it).  The subsequent strings are not verbatim, so the proper escape sequence would be `\"`.

You can make it look prettier with `string.Format`:

```
String formLookupPull = 
   string.Format(@"SELECT value1, '{0}', '{1}' FROM lkpLookups" +
                 @"WHERE ""table"" = '{0}' and ""field"" = '{1}';", 
                 tableName, columnName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `\"` to escape quotes, not `""`.

Like this:

```
.. FROM lkpLookups WHERE \"table\" = '" ..
```

**Edit:**

Further explanation:

You only have an `@` on the first of all the strings you're concatenating. In literal strings (with an `@` in front) you escape quotes with a double quote. In normal strings, it's slash-quote.

Eg.

```
string s = @"this is a literal string with ""quotes"" in it, " 
         +  "and this is a normal string with \"quotes\" in it";

string t = @"two literal strings" + @", concatenated together.";
```

Comment: Verbatim string literals don't use \ as an escape character, the only escape sequence is "", which is what's being used. The problem is that the verbatim string identifier, @, is only being applied to the first string, not the ones being appended with +.

Comment: The problem is that he is using the wrong escape sequence for his string type. He can either change the string to literal (as you say), or change the escape sequence (as I said)

Comment: Agreed, but your original answer implied that "" was incorrect in the general sense, so it was likely to confuse someone who isn't too familiar with verbatim string literals. Your revised answer is much clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Well after your first end of quote, the @ symbol is no longer being used anyways so you are free to use the escape character.  Try putting your "table" wrapped in '[' like [table] and [field] or escaping the " character with a \.

```
String formLookupPull = @"SELECT value1, '" + tableName + "', '" + columnName + "' FROM lkpLookups WHERE [table] = '" + tableName + "' and [field] = '" + columnName + "';";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot use SQL Parameters, String.Format can be little cleaner and readable than pure "+ concatenation".

```
string formLookupPull = 
  string.Format(@"SELECT value1, '{0}', '{1}' 
                       FROM lkpLookups 
                   WHERE ""table"" = '{0}' AND ""field"" = '{1}';",
                tableName, columnName);
```

Comment: This may be one such case...I'm using a library which doesn't expose any of that stuff to me and i'm trying to stick to it as much as possible because it comes with a few side effects that i'd have to reproduce otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

```
String formLookupPull = @"SELECT value1, '"+tableName+"', '"+columnName+"' FROM lkpLookups WHERE \"table\" = '" + tableName + "' and \"field\" = '" + columnName + "';";
```

I also trust that you are escaping these variables correctly before building this query :)

Comment: lol yea let's hope so, i was given a DLL with all the functions for performing DB IO inside of it...  I'm pretty sure it does proper SQL escaping but I didnt really look to closely...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you quoting the literal names of the columns, seem unnecessary to me.

"SELECT value1, " + tableName + "," + columnName +" FROM lkpLookups WHERE table = '" + tableName + "' and field = '" = columnName + "';";

Not tested but I think you will get the idea.