# C# Command Including Additional Variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm having trouble working a variable into an existing code fragment.  I'm sure its something simple I'm missing, but I'm not getting anywhere.

This is the current code, which has no errors:

```
new SqlCommand(@"xp_cmdshell 'bcp ""SELECT tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode, employee.employeeFName + '' '' + employee.employeeLName AS employeeName, tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID, SUM(tipReportingSummaryView.netChargeTips) AS netChargeTips, tipReportingSummaryView.positionCode, rvc.rvcName, ''CHG TIPS'' AS tipType FROM tipReportingSummaryView INNER JOIN employee ON tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID = employee.employeeID INNER JOIN rvc ON tipReportingSummaryView.rvcID = rvc.rvcID WHERE (tipReportingSummaryView.businessDate >= (dateadd(day,(-15),datediff(day,(0),getdate())))) AND (tipReportingSummaryView.businessDate <= (dateadd)) AND (tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode = 1) GROUP BY tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode, employee.employeeFName + employee.employeeLName, tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID, tipReportingSummaryView.positionCode, rvc.rvcName, employee.employeeFName + '' '' + employee.employeeLName HAVING SUM(tipReportingSummaryView.netChargeTips) <> 0"" queryout " + filePath + " -U sa -P password -c -t ,'", conn))
```

I want (tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode = ) to be equal to the value of the payGroup variable, so something like this:

```
new SqlCommand(@"xp_cmdshell 'bcp ""SELECT tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode, employee.employeeFName + '' '' + employee.employeeLName AS employeeName, tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID, SUM(tipReportingSummaryView.netChargeTips) AS netChargeTips, tipReportingSummaryView.positionCode, rvc.rvcName, ''CHG TIPS'' AS tipType FROM tipReportingSummaryView INNER JOIN employee ON tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID = employee.employeeID INNER JOIN rvc ON tipReportingSummaryView.rvcID = rvc.rvcID WHERE (tipReportingSummaryView.businessDate >= (dateadd(day,(-15),datediff(day,(0),getdate())))) AND (tipReportingSummaryView.businessDate <= (dateadd)) AND (tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode = " + payGroup + ") GROUP BY tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode, employee.employeeFName + employee.employeeLName, tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID, tipReportingSummaryView.positionCode, rvc.rvcName, employee.employeeFName + '' '' + employee.employeeLName HAVING SUM(tipReportingSummaryView.netChargeTips) <> 0"" queryout " + filePath + " -U sa -P password -c -t ,'", conn))
```

**Summary Version**

Current:

```
(tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode =1)
```

Desired:

```
(tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode = " + payGroup + ")
```

By adding " + payGroup + ", I get all kinds of syntax errors on that line, so its obviously causing it to bomb out.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think payGroup is a local variable, and he wants its value in the string.

Comment: You might want to post the specific syntax error that you get.

Comment: @crashmstr - Yeah, that figures (removed former comment to prevent any confusion)

Comment: You should probably use SqlParameters.  You won't have to worry about wrapping things in quotes then, plus it prevents SqlInjection.

Comment: @PeteGO: yes. More specifically SqlCommand has a Parameters, which is an SqlParameterCollection. You refer to the parameters like this in the SQl command text "@param1". And add them like this: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("... where something=@param1 ..."); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", paramvalue);

Comment: I'll look at the SqlParameters.  It is probably the better way to do this, but I wasn't familiar with it.  Using the string literals as outlined in the original snippet, adding @ in front of the string allows it to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place another @ before the second string literal - else the double quotes will fail to compile (it will think it's two literals back to back) - as below.

Isolated: `" + payGroup + @"`

```
new SqlCommand(@"xp_cmdshell 'bcp ""SELECT tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode, employee.employeeFName + '' '' + employee.employeeLName AS employeeName, tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID, SUM(tipReportingSummaryView.netChargeTips) AS netChargeTips, tipReportingSummaryView.positionCode, rvc.rvcName, ''CHG TIPS'' AS tipType FROM tipReportingSummaryView INNER JOIN employee ON tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID = employee.employeeID INNER JOIN rvc ON tipReportingSummaryView.rvcID = rvc.rvcID WHERE (tipReportingSummaryView.businessDate >= (dateadd(day,(-15),datediff(day,(0),getdate())))) AND (tipReportingSummaryView.businessDate <= (dateadd)) AND (tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode = " + payGroup + @") GROUP BY tipReportingSummaryView.payGroupCode, employee.employeeFName + employee.employeeLName, tipReportingSummaryView.employeeID, tipReportingSummaryView.positionCode, rvc.rvcName, employee.employeeFName + '' '' + employee.employeeLName HAVING SUM(tipReportingSummaryView.netChargeTips) <> 0"" queryout " + filePath + @" -U sa -P password -c -t ,'", conn))
```

You should probably put one after the filePath concatenation also.

See "Verbatim Strings" here: [MSDN Page On Strings](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx&ei=OltsUZ-GDcil0wWyuoGQDQ&usg=AFQjCNEbbq5U1cv3vxiy88ctxj5dhLCoZw&sig2=TTdnwFSY_i3OXr3z0TrpcA&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k) (sorry, couldn't find a page specifically for them)

Edit: similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652310/escaping-verbatim-string-literals)

Comment: Thanks!  That is what was confusing me since it wasn't requiring anything different with the filePath concatenation.  @ before the string fixed it.